# Multiple skype instances on iphone

Tags: iphone, skype

Is is possible to run multiple instances of skype client on an iphone.

I would like to be able to to login to two separate skype accounts and have the run simultaneously.

Is it possible?

For instance, if there was an unofficial skype client, I could install it along the official one with different user name.

Comment: just out of curiosity: why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not possible with the official Skype App.

Running unofficial Skype client is possible, but recently Skype changed the rules and pushed out third parties, running Skype gateways (like Fring).